# How to from groups from nodes without changing order?

Tags: xml, xslt, grouping

Let's say that we have some items which are either fruits or clothes:

```
<items>
    <orange/>
    <banana/>
    <apple/>
    <jacket/>
    <shirt/>
    <trousers/>
    <apple/>
    <banana/>
    <jacket/>
    <apple/>
    <banana/>
</items>
```

And I would like them to be grouped following way without changing order of items:

```
<items>
    <fruits>
        <orange/>
        <banana/>
        <apple/>
    </fruits>
    <clothes>
        <jacket/>
        <shirt/>
        <trousers/>
    </clothes>
    <fruits>
        <apple/>
        <banana/>
    </fruits>
    <clothes>
        <jacket/>
    </clothes>
    <fruits>
        <apple/>
        <banana/>
    </fruits>
</items>
```

I am complete beginner what comes to XSLT and after browsing through countless examples I still don't have a clue whatsoever how achieve that using XSLT.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this? Maybe the problem you're trying to solve has a better solution than this type of grouping.

Comment: @JimGarrison, One reason I could think is, it would be more easily readable for **other** users. Some one who doesn't know if _jacket_ belongs in cloth or fruit category ;) (well. the example can be upgraded to some generally unknown stuffs to an average person, like grouping chemicals?)

Comment: @JimGarrison, and MtP, the grouping could have been more simpler by grouping all fruits in one block and all clothes in other .. But, well. I assume this might be packets of information which user doesn't want to mix up.

Comment: @JimGarrison I have rest api which is using another rest api to retrieve data. Data is much more complex than in my example. Problem I described is just generalized and human readable version of problem I am having. I am not even sure if I should use xlst to solve my problem but I would like learn about xlst and it's limits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any kind of grouping is easier in XSLT2 than XSLT1 so I'll assume XSLT2 as you didn't say

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:f="data:f"
        exclude-result-prefixes="f">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="items">
 <xsl:for-each-group select="*"
             group-adjacent="f:type(.)">
  <xsl:element name="{current-grouping-key()}">
   <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:function name="f:type">
 <xsl:param name="n"/>
 <xsl:apply-templates mode="type" select="$n"/>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template mode="type" match="orange|banana|apple">fruits</xsl:template>

<xsl:template mode="type" match="shirt|trousers|jacket">clothes</xsl:template>

<xsl:template mode="type" match="*">x</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I would not have thought of using apply-templates to implement a user-defined function.

Comment: Any kind of grouping is easier in XSLT2 than XSLT1. agreed ..!